# Can't install python avro library

Tags: python, pip, avro

I cannot seem to install certain packages that have `avro` as a dependency. In fact, I cannot install avro at all.

```
$ pip install avro==1.10.0 
 
Collecting avro==1.10.0 
    Using cached avro-1.10.0.tar.gz (67 kB) 
    WARNING: Requested avro==1.10.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/6f/75fb40defc4e2316d5088f635223b57518f59320a13fc12f430a17e4dc48/avro-1.10.0.tar.gz#sha256=bbf9f89fd20b4cf3156f10ec9fbce83579ece3e0403546c305957f9dac0d2f03, but installing version file-.avro-VERSION.txt 
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/6f/75fb40defc4e2316d5088f635223b57518f59320a13fc12f430a17e4dc48/avro-1.10.0.tar.gz#sha256=bbf9f89fd20b4cf3156f10ec9fbce83579ece3e0403546c305957f9dac0d2f03 (from https://pypi.org/simple/avro/). Requested avro==1.10.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/6f/75fb40defc4e2316d5088f635223b57518f59320a13fc12f430a17e4dc48/avro-1.10.0.tar.gz#sha256=bbf9f89fd20b4cf3156f10ec9fbce83579ece3e0403546c305957f9dac0d2f03 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.10.0', but metadata has 'file-.avro-VERSION.txt' 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement avro==1.10.0 (from versions: 1.3.3, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2) ERROR: No matching distribution found for avro==1.10.0
```

I get the same results for `1.10.1` and `1.10.2`

FYI, here are the packages I'm trying to install

```
confluent-kafka
apache-beam
requests
certifi
```

I'm using `pip==21.2.4`, doesn't work with `pip==21.1.3` either.

Comment: Try download avro from https://pypi.org/project/avro/1.10.0/ and install manually using ``python setup.py install``

Comment: @Matin, for real? that's so bad though... How come it's not possible to go through package manager...

Comment: That seems so strange. I checked [here](https://pypi.org/project/avro/) right now that the latest version is the 1.10.2. You can try to just `pip install avro` without a specific version and see what happens (it should install the compatible version for you), then posting the result so we can dig more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading both `setuptools` and if you haven't already `pip`